# Ruby on Rails "The action 'create' could not be found for MessagesController"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an issue with Ruby on Rails routing.

config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :messages

  root to: 'dashboards#show'

end
```

app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        # Do current user messages select from database here
    end

end
```

link to messges:

```
<%= button_to 'messages', messages_path %>
```

URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/messages
```

Error:

```
The action 'create' could not be found for MessagesController
```

Why I have this issue? What am I doing wrong? Why I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [button_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) method does a post by default. When you have specified the route as a resource, it maps a post to the #create method. You need to define that method, stop using a post, or modify your routes.rb to send a post to a different method. From the looks of how you are using it, you should probably just modify the button_to to use a get:

```
<%= button_to 'messages', messages_path, method: :get %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a create method in your MessagesController:

```
def create
end
```

Comment: What if I don't need it?

Comment: And of course `Missing template messages/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.`

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the `button_to` helper ([link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to)) says:

> ...If no :method modifier is given, it will default to performing a POST operation

E.g by default `button_to` will wrap the button in a form that has uses a POST method instead of a GET method. The `messages_path` path with a GET request goes to the index method in the MessagesController however `message_path` with a POST request gets routed to the `create` method. As you don't have a create method defined, you're getting the 'Action not found' error.

To fix this set the method for `button_to` as GET:

```
<%= button_to 'messages', messages_path, method: 'GET' %>
```